# Grunt "watch" Warning: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Grunt "Watch" doesn't want to proceed.

Problem: 
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Warning: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Here is the grunt watch in Gruntfile.js:

```
watch: {
  //Watch files for changes during "grunt serve"
  main: {
    options: {
        livereload: true,
        livereloadOnError: false,
        spawn: false
    },
    files: [createFolderGlobs(['*.js', '*.less','*.html','*.json']), '!src/bower_components/**/*.js', '!src/js/**/*.js', '!_SpecRunner.html','!.grunt'],
    tasks: [] //all the tasks are run dynamically during the watch event handler

  }
},
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the issue. You need to upgrade grunt-contrib-jshint.

I had version "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.9"

changed to "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0"

error is now gone!

Answer (score 3):

*I figured it out while I wrote this question*.

---

When I added tags for this question I saw the tag **grunt-contrib-watch** and got to: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch.

and did this:

```
$ npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
```

...Now it works. I posted it anyway because I couldn't find something about this when I googled.

Comment: For others, this doesn't work for me.  `watch` has always been installed.  It could very easily be something else.